# SQL concat case select when trying to add new column of previous month data

Tags: sql, select, case, concatenation

I have a data set in which I need to concat month and year for the previous month.  the problem is it spans over two years.  I need to create a statement in which mean the month - 1 = 0, month becomes 12 and year-1.

```
Select concat(case
when month > 1 then select(month-1, year)
when month = 1 then select(12, year -1)
else select(month-1, year)
end
```

as monthyear
from table

Comment: Please link which type of DBMS (Oracle, mySQL, postgre, etc) that you are using

Comment: I am using SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 CASE statements inside concat(), for the month and the year:

```
select 
  concat(
    case when month > 1 then month - 1 else 12 end,
    case when month > 1 then year else year - 1 end
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `month` and `year` as separate columns and want to subtract one month, then you can use:

```
select (case when month > 1 then year else year - 1 end) as year,
       (case when month > 1 then month - 1 else 12 end) as month
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach (tried with SQLite3, adjust accordingly to your SQL syntax):

```
-- some test data first

create table t(yy,mm);
insert into t values
  (2018,1),(2018,2),(2018,3),(2018,4),(2018,5),(2018,6),
  (2018,7),(2018,8),(2018,9),(2018,10),(2018,11),(2018,12),

  (2019,1),(2019,2),(2019,3),(2019,4),(2019,5),(2019,6),
  (2019,7),(2019,8),(2019,9),(2019,10),(2019,11),(2019,12),

  (2020,1),(2020,2),(2020,3),(2020,4),(2020,5),(2020,6),
  (2020,7),(2020,8),(2020,9),(2020,10),(2020,11),(2020,12);

-- current year and month, year of previous month and previous month

select yy,mm,yy-((mm+10)%12+1)/12 as yy_1,(mm+10)%12+1 mm_1 from t;
```